# How do I keep my web service to myself?

Tags: web-services

Say, if I create a web service serving some data for my mobile application. The data could be anything like stock price or weather. I don't want others to use the web service maybe because the server resource is expensive or maybe the data is confidential.

I believe the URL is not a secret because anyone can use Wireshark to get it. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the answer is simple: `Authentication for Web Services`. But unless you provide more information on the language the web service is implemented, it's hard to answer with a concrete example. If the transferred data are confidential, you might want to use a encrypted service (https).

Comment: Thanks Thor, but how can I do the authentication? Assume I am using PHP and the user registration is not required(no username/password in this case), how can we authenticate the user?

Comment: At least you need **something** for the authentication process. This can be a token, OAUTH protocol, Kerberos, LDAP or simply a username/password. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323939 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105389